# Network problems: no data receivable from all Ubuntu Devices

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

The following is my problem: With my two Ubuntu devices, I am unable to get data from the internet. I can ping my router successfully, but pinging other ips like 8.8.8.8 does not work. I am connected via LAN.

The problem occurs only with the network I am with right now, in other networks it works fine. Moreover, in the current network, all the other devices (Windows, Android) can connect to the internet.

Do you have any ideas, what the problem could be? Ubuntu versions of the two devices are 16 and 18.

Below some information from my ubuntu 16 device:

```
gnoasti@jetson-flashing-machine:~$ nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         E8:03:9A:0E:DC:2C
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         169.254.0.29/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            169.254.0.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             169.254.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e06d:31c0:adc3:a8e5/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         C4:85:08:68:8E:4A
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            
gnoasti@jetson-flashing-machine:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         169.254.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
gnoasti@jetson-flashing-machine:~$ ping 169.254.0.1
PING 169.254.0.1 (169.254.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 169.254.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.721 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.650 ms
^C
--- 169.254.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1026ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.650/0.685/0.721/0.044 ms
gnoasti@jetson-flashing-machine:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2040ms
```

EDIT: The output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
gnoasti@jetson-flashing-machine:~$ sudo lshw -C network
sudo: unable to resolve host jetson-flashing-machine
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 24
       serial: c4:85:08:68:8e:4a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-88-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:29 memory:f0500000-f0501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 06
       serial: e8:03:9a:0e:dc:2c
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=169.254.0.29 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Also, if you disconnect your ethernet, and connect with wireless, does it work? Are you on DSL or cable modem? Does your computer go to a switch/hub or directly to the router LAN ports?

Comment: I edited my question. If I disconnect from Ethernet and connect to wireless, it also does not work. I am on DSL. The computer goes directly to the router LAN ports. It is worth noting, that with the Windows distribution that I have on the same laptop, everything works.

Comment: You may have multiple problems. First, POWER cycle the router by UNPLUGGING it from AC power, count to 15, replug to AC power, wait 20 seconds, reboot the computer, and retry both wireless and wired. In both cases, note what IP address the machine gets via DHCP. Report back.

Comment: Wired: IP is 169.254.0.29
Wireless: IP is 169.254.0.22

Comment: Very strange. Tell me what IP the Windows machine has. What brand router? Is the router plugged into a DSL/cable modem? If so, POWER cycle BOTH the modem AND the router, and reboot the computer. Then recheck IP addresses again. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 ethernet cables from the computer, to the router? I ask because your link speed is 1/10th the speed it's capable of. Usually it's a cable problem. Report back.

Comment: IP of windows machine is 169.254.0.39. AFAIK the router assigns IPs between 169.254.0.2x and 169.254.0.2x. Network setup is signal -> ntba splitter-> FritzBox -> Computer. I power cycled all devices but IPs are the same. Brand is Fritzbox, model is 3170. I am using the cat 5e cable between computer and router.

Comment: Help me understand the hardware... is the ntba splitter a multiport splitter, and if so, what do the other ports go to? The FritzBox appears to be a DSL modem. So what MTU do you have set in your "Wired Connection" profile? Install `iputils-tracepath` and then run `tracepath www.ebay.de` (or some other web site). Put that output into your question.

Comment: Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I changed my router and it worked without problems. So pretty sure it was a router issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

The IP address you show (169.254.0.29) is a "[Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)" which "is valid only for communications within the network segment or the broadcast domain that the host is connected to".

So it will never be routed outside your current network segment.

Make sure your interface either:

- has a valid IP address and gateway for yout network
- or is configured to use DHCP, and the router or some other device on the network has a DHCP server giving out IP addresses.

Comment: I understand that. My router uses DHCP, my other devices are also connected via a link-local adress and here it works. I configured my connection also on DHCP(Automatic).